# Ember Client Side Authentication, route authentication

Tags: javascript, authentication, ember.js

I have been googling about this a lot but haven't been able to find satisfactory answer or solution you can say.

I have this Ember app, http://jsbin.com/aHiVIwU/28#.

My use case is pretty simple. I want to show the user whole app only after user gets authenticated. I am not using Ember Data as you can see, so the authentication will be through  `$.ajax` as well.

If I am not wrong, I would have a template for login page like this,

```
 <script type="text/x-handlebars" id="login">
            <h1>Login</h1>
           {{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="username"}}
           {{view Ember.TextField type="password" valueBinding="password"}}
           <button {{action 'login' class="btn"}}>Login</button>
 </script>
```

Then I would map the resource,

```
App.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource( 'login'); 
});
```

And then there would be a corresponding controller right?

```
App.LoginController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
});
```

But the point where I am getting stuck is, how will I show only the login template first and then the whole app after the user gets authenticated? I would appreciate some explanation & help on this.

Answer (score 2):

I can't say it any better than how Alex talked about it in his pull request with router facelift in ember.  Look about a quarter of the way down, for '**How do I redirect to a login form for an authenticated route and retry the original transition later?**':

https://gist.github.com/machty/5647589

Essentially at the root route of the resource where a user needs to be authenticated you will save the current transition, transition to the login route, then after they've authenticated, restart the previous transition.

He included a very simplistic example, where he's created a mixin that could be attached to all the routes requiring authentication and you wouldn't have to duplicate code etc.

http://jsbin.com/axarop/54/edit

```
App.NeedsAuthMixin = Ember.Mixin.create({
  beforeModel: function(transition) {
    // We're using beforeModel here to
    // make sure the user is authenticated.
    var loginController = this.controllerFor('login');
    if (!loginController.get('hasLoggedIn')) {
      alert('you must log in!');
      loginController.set('afterLoginTransition', transition);
      this.transitionTo('login');
    }
  }
});

App.ArticlesRoute = Ember.Route.extend(App.NeedsAuthMixin);

App.LoginRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  events: {
    login: function () {
      this.controller.set('hasLoggedIn', true);
      var savedTransition = this.controller.get('afterLoginTransition');
      if (savedTransition) {
        this.controller.set('afterLoginTransition', null);
        savedTransition.retry();
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: I actually decided to go with Yehuda's JSBin, http://jsbin.com/eQOZoGe/329/edit as it was much simpler and easy to use. I am hoping that I might also come up with some other solution of mine which I will definitely share with you guys :)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Client-side Authentication screen casts on http://www.embercasts.com/. They are from the same guy that made the examples that kingpin2k referenced, but provides a full, working solution.