# Ember.js: Pathless Transitional Route

Tags: javascript, ajax, ember.js

New to ember.js. What I'm trying to do is: create a transitional route that has no path, that I can pass an AJAX promise to as the model when I transition to it, and then it makes a redirect decision once the promise completes. I want the LoadingRoute view to be invoked while this is happening. I've tried to accomplish that with the following route:

```
App.LoginUserRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    setupController: function(controller, model) {
        //Model should be a promise
        model.then(this.success.bind(this),this.failure.bind(this));
    },

    success: function (data) {
        if (data.success) {
            App.loggedInUser = App.User.create(data);
            console.log(App.loggedInUser);
            //Make redirection decision
        }
        else {
            alert(data.error);
        }
    },

    failure: function () {
        //Failure code
    }
});
```

However, when I try to pass the promise to the route like follows:

```
var request = $.post("api.php", {action: 'create_user', username: this.username, password: this.password});
this.transitionToRoute('loginUser',request);
```

I get the error "More context objects were passed than there are dynamic segments for the route: loginUser" because I'm trying to create a pathless route and Ember requires that the model be serialized into the path when passed using transitionToRoute().

The reason I need this is:

- The login event can happen from multiple controllers (when the user registers, when they login using the login screen, or when the application first loads if the right cookie is detected) and I don't want to duplicate the login logic across all those controllers.
- After the login completes, there's multiple different routes the user could then be directed to, depending on the nature of the returned user object.
- I want the LoadingRoute to be invoked while the request is completing.

I assume the solution to my problem is not to use routing, but rather something else. However, I'm not sure what the "something else" would be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I achieved what I was trying to do by adding the following code to ApplicationController

```
loginUser: function (request) {
    this.transitionToRoute('loading');
    request.then(this.loginRequestSuccess.bind(this),this.loginRequestFailure.bind(this));
},

loginRequestSuccess: function (data) {
    if (data.success) {
        App.loggedInUser = App.User.create(data.user);
        console.log(App.loggedInUser);
        //Route transition decision
    }
    else {
        alert(data.error);
    }
},

loginRequestFailure: function () {
    //Failure code
}
```

And then calling the loginUser() function with the jqXHR object from wherever in the code a login request was made.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to take advantage of a mixin, and hooking into the transition route.

The following SO answer will work for all of your needs:

[Ember Client Side Authentication, route authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19614251/ember-client-side-authentication-route-authentiction/19615347#19615347)

Comment: I don't see how this deals with my issue of there being multiple ways for a user to log in (by registering, by logging in, or by cookie, with each way triggering a different type of AJAX request to api.php.) I need something I can pass a jqXHR or promise to, have it invoke the LoadingRoute, and then make a route redirect decision once the jqXHR/promise completes.

Comment: But +1 because I didn't know about this functionality and it will come in handy.